# "Managed by your organization" in Google Chrome browser

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, google-chrome

My Chrome browser (Windows 10) shows "Managed by your organization" at the end of the menu. I went into the chrome://policy/ and saw some policies that seem to be set exclusively by active directory group policy like ChromeCleanupEnabled=false. At the left says:

Status-Google Update-Enrollment domain:myLocalDomain

I went to the group policies on the active directory server but didn't see anything about chrome policies. It has only 5 GPOs and none of them have anything to do with Chrome policies. Where is the source of this configuration?

[image]

Comment: `I went to the group policies on the active directory server`. You need to review the policies on the endpoint. That is what gpresult /h will do.

Comment: I think I'm on the right track. I run gpresult /h but it throws ERROR: Invalid pointer. I run equivalent gpresult /v and shows me that my computer is under two GPOs. Default Domain Policy (there is nothing about Chrome) and Local Group Policy and here there are the previous policies! But I went to the local computer policies editor (GPEDIT.MSC) and I didn't find them! I went to Computer Configuration-->Administrative Templates-->All Settings to found them

Comment: Usually this means there are artifacts of a policy located at HKLM\Software\Policies\Google\Chrome\. Renaming the Chrome registry key would be a good start.  https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/9131254?sjid=9250410863732215112-NA

Comment: Rename or delete? When rename it continues to exist as policy in chrome:\\policy with the new name of course

Comment: Sorry you said "Chrome" registry key. It is ok now. Can I delete it?